# JSON parse URL with PHP JSON decode

Tags: php, arrays, json, url

I have JSON data:

```
{"took":3,
"timed_out":false,
"_shards":{ "total":5,
            "successful":5,
            "failed":0
            },
"hits":{"total":105,
        "max_score":1.0,
        "hits":[
            {"_index":"csv",
            "_type":"logs",
            "_id":"AVeyr-BQodQ9UhW1sdW0",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{"message":"james,wonder\r",
                        "@version":"1",
                        "@timestamp":"2016-10-11T07:40:52.332Z",
                        "path":"D:\\logstash-2.4.0\\bin\\Book1.csv",
                        "host":"CHNL-LT-544",
                        "fname":"fa1368a93aa39b2346329c1734be1f4b",
                        "lname":"wonder"
                        }
            },
            {"_index":"csv",
            "_type":"logs",
            "_id":"AVeyr-BQodQ9UhW1sdW1",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{"message":"muskaan, wonder\r",
            "@version":"1",
            "@timestamp":"2016-10-11T07:40:52.332Z",
            "path":"D:\\logstash-2.4.0\\bin\\Book1.csv",
            "host":"CHNL-LT-544",
            "fname":"479085e94d305129527fa80978613e95",
            "lname":"wonder"}
            },  
{"_index":"csv","_type":"logs","_id":"AVeyr-BQodQ9UhW1sdW3","_score":1.0,"_source":{"message":"altimetrik,india\r","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-10-11T07:40:52.333Z","path":"D:\\logstash-2.4.0\\bin\\Book1.csv","host":"CHNL-LT-544","fname":"8b3ecf275832c79b36d62d74f47257c9","lname":"india"}},{"_index":"csv","_type":"logs","_id":"AVeyr-BQodQ9UhW1sdW8","_score":1.0,"_source":{"message":"kool,indiae\r","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-10-11T07:40:52.335Z","path":"D:\\logstash-2.4.0\\bin\\Book1.csv","host":"CHNL-LT-544","fname":"d2edbdce885720c70f38f36748c37600","lname":"indiae"}},{"_index":"csv","_type":"logs","_id":"AVeyr-BQodQ9UhW1sdXA","_score":1.0,"_source":{"message":"ds,dssd\r","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-10-11T07:40:52.336Z","path":"D:\\logstash-2.4.0\\bin\\Book1.csv","host":"CHNL-LT-544","fname":"91594a75bc6bfb0ec800d4f454e1fe87","lname":"dssd"}},{"_index":"csv","_type":"logs","_id":"AVeytJ0iodQ9UhW1sdXf","_score":1.0,"_source":{"message":"kool,india\r","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-10-11T07:46:02.839Z","path":"D:\\logstash-2.4.0\\bin\\Book1.csv","host":"CHNL-LT-544","fname":"d2edbdce885720c70f38f36748c37600","lname":"india"}},{"_index":"csv","_type":"logs","_id":"AVeytJ0iodQ9UhW1sdXi","_score":1.0,"_source":{"message":"karnataka,india\r","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-10-11T07:46:02.840Z","path":"D:\\logstash-2.4.0\\bin\\Book1.csv","host":"CHNL-LT-544","fname":"2a0785caed6bfd2ffb6ad5a449f2bd0e","lname":"india"}},{"_index":"csv","_type":"logs","_id":"AVeytv9hodQ9UhW1sdXq","_score":1.0,"_source":{"message":"james,wonder\r","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-10-11T07:48:39.550Z","path":"D:\\logstash-2.4.0\\bin\\Book1.csv","host":"CHNL-LT-544","fname":"fa1368a93aa39b2346329c1734be1f4b","lname":"wonder"}},{"_index":"csv","_type":"logs","_id":"AVeytv9hodQ9UhW1sdX0","_score":1.0,"_source":{"message":"rajasthan,india\r","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-10-11T07:48:39.558Z","path":"D:\\logstash-2.4.0\\bin\\Book1.csv","host":"CHNL-LT-544","fname":"449b07d9038569b2d69243dadfae0371","lname":"india"}},{"_index":"csv","_type":"logs","_id":"AVeytv9hodQ9UhW1sdX5","_score":1.0,"_source":{"message":"najeeb,shariff\r","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-10-11T07:48:39.573Z","path":"D:\\logstash-2.4.0\\bin\\Book1.csv","host":"CHNL-LT-544","fname":"be7a5e98258338fa63086f44e8bd1850","lname":"shariff"}}]}}
```

I want to print only 2 fields from this JSON; `fname` and `lname`. Please tell me how I can achieve this using PHP.

```
$url = 'localhost:9200/csv/_search';; 
$content = file_get_contents($url); 
$json = json_decode($content, true); 
foreach($json['hits'] as $item) { 
    print $item['fname']; 
}
```

But getting error Undefined index

Comment: So where are you stuck? You found the important function already `json_decode()`.

Comment: Dude, the title of your question has the answer!

Comment: i am trying with this '$url = 'http://localhost:9200/csv/_search';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json['hits'] as $item) {
    print $item['fname'];
}' but getting error Undefined index

Comment: @Areik Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just do a `print_r($json);` and you will be able to see the structure of the data

Comment: Just a note: That json string validates on `jsonlint.com` but when I try and `json_decode()` it in PHP it generates an error !! Odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = 'localhost:9200/csv/_search';; 
$content = file_get_contents($url); 
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json['hits']['hits'] as $item) { 
    echo "<p>{$item['_source']['fname']}</p>";
    echo "<p>{$item['_source']['lname']}</p>";
}
```

Array path of `fname` and `lname` goes like `[hits][hits][0][_source][fname]` and `[hits][hits][0][_source][lname]`. `[hits][hits]` should be iterated in the loop to access each `_source` element.

As **RiggsFolly** said, you need to do `print_r($json)` to see how the array is structured especially when you encounter nested arrays.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I personally prefer to leave objects as object, but this is the basic idea

Comment: Thanks alot perumal and Riggs for solving my issue.

Comment: As you commented that the JSON string in the question is validated on `jsonlint.com` and doesn't work in PHP with json_decode, yeah, I noted the same as well. The string doesn't work. It generates error in your case. In my case, it parses the string and doesn't output anything from the `json_decode`.

Comment: i am trying to access all the values in the field cat_name but sometimes it will have 3 or only 2 value how can i handle dynamically. Currently i am trying with this $item['_source']['cat_name'] [1] and json looks like "cat_name" : [ "primary", "secondary", "backup" ] and sometimes "cat_name" : [ "primary", "secondary" ]